# Is there a way to make While function with two condition?

Tags: python-3.x

When I run my code, it runs even I input 1 or 2.

I already did with `while a != 1 or 2:`, `while a != 1 or a !=2:`

```
a = 0
while a != 1 or a !=2:
    a = int(input('Input: '))
print('end')
```

I want to know the way make while with two condition break without using 'break' method.

Comment: please clearify what is your question.

Comment: The wording is a bit unclear,  but I suspect you want to break out of the while loop if the input is either 1 or 2.  A while loop evaluates a single expression, and if True, will keep iterating.  So your logic is a bit off.  it should probably be `a != 1 and a != 2`.  And a more pythonic expression would be `a not in (1, 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

`a` can never be 1 and 2 at the same time, so this is an infinite loop:

```
while a != 1 or a != 2:
```